# Select All Checkboxes On Click using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have following HTML:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="12" name="Cevent[]" /> Yoga</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="12" name="Cevent[]" /> Yoga 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="12" name="Cevent[]" /> Yoga 2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="12" name="Cevent[]" /> Yoga 3</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="selectAllEventList" name="selectAllE"> Select All</label>
```

and Following Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function (){

   $('#selectAllEventList').click (function () {
          $('input[name=Cevent[]]').each(function(){
          $(this).prop('checked', status);
          });

     });
 });
```

But i am getting Syntax error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name=Cevent[]]
```

I think i am writing wrong Selector at `input[name=Cevent[]]` what is the problem how can i write it correctly because i must have to send it as a array so i have to write it as Cevent[].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\` to `escape` `[`,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/fA3W2/)**

```
$(document).ready(function (){

   $('#selectAllEventList').click (function () {
          $('input[name*=Cevent\\[]').each(function(){
              if( $('#selectAllEventList').is(':checked'))
                   $(this).prop('checked',true);
              else
                   $(this).prop('checked',false);
          });

     });
 });​
```

Comment: not working :-( can you please provide the working example on jsfiddle?

Comment: It is on jsfiddle now, please have a look

Answer (score 2):

Quote the attribute value:

```
$('input[name="Cevent[]"]')
```

---

**Update**

I assume that your code is meant to check/uncheck all the `Cevent[]` checkboxes when the `selectAllE` checkbox is changed. If that's the case, you can shorten your code significantly, because most jQuery methods apply to every element in the matched set (there's no need to use `.each()`):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#selectAllEventList').click(function () {
        $('input[name="Cevent[]"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
});​
```

Comment: not working :-( can you please provide the working example on jsfiddle?

Comment: @PhpSeeker - http://jsfiddle.net/fA3W2/1/ - I've added the declaration of `status`, which you didn't show in your question... that may have been the problem?

Comment: @PhpSeeker - And, assuming my previous fiddle demonstrated the correct behaviour, here's a much shorter version of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/fA3W2/2/

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

[see Demo](http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp8i)

JS

```
$('#selectAllEventList').click (function () {
          $('.chkbox').each(function(){
          $(this).prop('checked', true);
          });

     });
```

HTML

```
<label><input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" value="12" name="Cevent[]" /> Yoga</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" value="12" name="Cevent[]" /> Yoga 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" value="12" name="Cevent[]" /> Yoga 2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" value="12" name="Cevent[]" /> Yoga 3</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="selectAllEventList" name="selectAllE"> Select All</label>
```